# Getting a javascript validation error on signup page when clicking "Create Account" button

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

heres the button

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server"  Text="Create Account" 
                         OnClientClick="return UserValueValidation();" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
```

heres the function itself

```
function UserValueValidation() {
    var fname, lname, email, pwd, cpwd,emailExp;
    fname = document.getElementById("TextBox6").value;
    lname = document.getElementById("TextBox5").value;
    email = document.getElementById("TextBox4").value;
    pwd = document.getElementById("TextBox3").value;
    cpwd = document.getElementById("TextBox7").value;
    emailExp = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([com\co\.\in])+$/;

    if (fname == '' && lname == '' && email == '' && pwd == '' && cpwd == '' && emailExp == '') {
        alert("Enter all fields");
        return false;
    }
    else {

        if (fname == ' ') {
            alert("Enter Name");
            return false;
        }
        if (lname == ' ') {
            alert("Enter lastname");
            return false;

        }
        if (email == ' ') {
            alert("Enter email");
            return false;
        }
        if (email != '') {
            if (!email.match(emailExp)) {
                alert("Invalid Email Id");
                return false;
            }
        }

        if (pwd == ' ') {
            alert("Enter password");
        }
        if (cpwd == ' ') {
            alert("Please confirn your password");
            return false;
        }
        if (pwd != cpwd) {
            alert("Passwords doesn't match");
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

On clicking create account the following message pops up

Javascript runtime error:UserValueValidation() is undefined...

upon click i have redirected the page to the new user acount page using session state...

Comment: Normally means there is a syntax error somewhere in your javascript (not necessarily in the function itself, but somewhere that is stopping the javascript from parsing correctly). Check the development tools in your browser using F12 (I recommend FireBug for FireFox)

Comment: Try putting a breakpoint on the Chrome debugger console and then check  that the said JS method is actually available (using the console).
Also, check the console for potential JS errors resulting in the failure of the method to load.

Comment: Can I see where `UserValueValidation` function is declared?

Comment: [___It is working___](http://codeshare.io/5qdfB)

Comment: are you using UserControl elements?

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment, there is a javascript error here...

```
if (fname == String. && lname == '' && email == '' && pwd == '' && cpwd == '' && emailExp == '') {
```

Instead of `fname == String.`, replace it with `fname == ''`

That should give you...

```
if (fname == '' && lname == '' && email == '' && pwd == '' && cpwd == '' && emailExp == '') {
```

---

You also probably want to replace all the other `if` statements as well, as they are all checking for a single space, when I think you want to check for an empty string.

So replace (for example)...

```
if (fname == ' ') {
```

With...

```
if (fname == '') {
```

Comment: done everything mentioned above but still getting the same error @freefaller

Comment: Then do as my comment says, check your development tools using F12